# ¿ por que mi aplicacion web en vue.js , va lenta en dispositvos moviles?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js

Hola estoy empezando a usar VUE.JS todo va bien en pc's de escritorio y laptops pero cuando abro la web en dispotivos moviles como celulares o tablets se pone en verdad muy lento.

Solo tengo un simple formulario y cuando se escribe algo en un input vinculado con un v-model las letras aparecen muy lento tambien cuando abro una ventanda de dialogo se nota un poco de lentitud. Me eh dado cuenta q todo lo que tiene un v-model se pone lento. Alguie le paso lo mismo?.
 Gracias de antemano.

NOTA: ya probé en varios dispositvos moviles y tambien noté que en celulares de gama alta no tiene lentitud por ejemplo probe en galaxy s9 y todo va bien pero en un lg k8 va lento tabien en una tableta samsung galaxy tab .

CON ESTO HAGO UNA LISTA :

```
 <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-group v-for="(piso,i) in pisos" :key="i">
              <v-list-tile slot="activator">
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title><h3>{{ piso.nombre_piso }}</h3></v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
              </v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile  v-for="(ambiente,e) in piso.ambientes" :key="e" >
                <v-list-tile-content  @click="OpenRegistro(piso.nombre_piso,ambiente)">
                <v-list-tile-title style="margin-left:50px;">{{ambiente}}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
              </v-list-tile>
            </v-list-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout >
```

ESTE ES MI CUADRO DE DIALOGO DENTRO ESTA MY FORMULARIO

```
      <v-card >
        <v-card-text>
          <v-card-title>
            <h2>REGISTRO DATOS DE AMBIENTE </h2> 
          </v-card-title>
          <v-container>
            <v-form>
              <v-text-field label="fecha" v-model="registro.fecha">
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field label="responsable" v-model="registro.responsable">
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field label="piso" v-model="registro.piso">
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field label="ambiente" v-model="registro.ambiente" >
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field label="Altura de medicion " v-model="registro.altura_medicion" >
              </v-text-field>

              <v-layout xs12  row justify-space-between>
                  <v-flex md3 xs1>
                  <h3> MEDICIÓN LUMINICA</h3>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex md3 xs8>
                    <v-btn color="red"  @click="addmedicion">
                      Agrega mediciÓn
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <v-layout xs12 v-for="(r,w) in registro.medicion_fotoluminica" :key="w" row justify-space-between>

                <v-flex md1 xs2 >
                  <v-icon @click="EliminaItem(registro.medicion_fotoluminica,w)" color="red lighten-1" class="rowPartida">
                    delete
                  </v-icon>
                  <v-chip label >{{ r.nro_medicion = w+1}}</v-chip>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex md1 xs3>
                  <v-text-field v-model="r.resultado"  label="resultado" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md3 xs5>
                  <v-text-field label="Descripción " v-model="r.decripcion" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md2 xs2>
                  <input type="file" multiple="true" v-on:change="uploadFotos(r,$event)">
                </v-flex>

              </v-layout>

              <v-layout row justify-space-between>
                  <v-flex xs3 md3 >
                    <h3> LUMINARIAS</h3>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex md3 xs7>
                    <v-btn color="red"  @click="addluminaria">
                      Agrega luminaria
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <v-layout row justify-space-between  v-for="(a,o) in registro.tipo_luminarias" :key="'C'+o">
                <v-flex md1 xs1 >
                    <v-icon @click="EliminaItem(registro.tipo_luminarias,o)" color="red lighten-1" class="rowPartida">
                    delete
                  </v-icon>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md3 xs6 >
                    <v-autocomplete v-model="a.nombre_luminaria" :items="luminarias" placeholder="tipo de luminaria"></v-autocomplete>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md1 xs2>
                  <v-text-field  v-model="a.cantidad" label="cantidad" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md1 xs2>
                  <v-autocomplete v-model="a.estado" :items="estados" placeholder="estado" ></v-autocomplete>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md2 xs2>
                  <v-text-field label="Observacion " v-model="a.observacion" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

              <v-layout row justify-space-between>
                  <v-flex md3 xs6 >
                  <h3>  SENSORES</h3>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex md3 xs6 >
                    <v-btn color="red"  @click="addsensores">
                      Agrega SENSOR
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <v-layout row justify-space-between v-for="(f,g) in registro.tipo_sensores" :key="'A'+g">
                <v-flex md1 xs1>
                  <v-icon @click="EliminaItem(registro.tipo_sensores,g)" color="red lighten-1" class="rowPartida">
                    delete
                  </v-icon>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md3 xs6 >
                    <v-autocomplete v-model="f.nombre_sensor" :items="sensores"  placeholder="tipo de sensores"></v-autocomplete>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md1 xs1>
                  <v-text-field v-model="f.cantidad"  label="cantidad" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex row md2 xs3>
                <v-autocomplete v-model="f.estado" :items="estados" placeholder="estado" ></v-autocomplete>
                </v-flex>
                 <v-flex md2 xs3>
                  <v-text-field label="Observacion " v-model="f.observacion" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <v-layout xs12 row justify-space-between>
                  <v-flex  md3  xs6>
                  <h3>   INTERRUPTORES </h3>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex md3 xs4> 
                    <v-text-field  v-model="registro.interruptores_cantidad"  label="cantidad" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex md2 xs5>
                  <v-text-field v-model="registro.interruptores_observaciones"   label="observaciones" >
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-form>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-layout row justify-space-between class="mt-3">
              <v-flex>
                <v-btn color="blue accent-4" @click="guardar">GUARDAR</v-btn>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-btn  color="grey darken-2primary" @click="cerrar">CERRAR</v-btn>
              </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>

  </v-dialog>
```

Comment: No se como podriamos ayudarte. si vas a poner codigo, tiene que ir en la pregunta.

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo del form para ver como lo tienes y ayudarte..!!

Comment: Puedes usar el devtools y mirar la memoria que consumes con javascript y mirar su procedencia es decir si vue esta utilizando muchos recursos, aunque lo dudo.

Comment: Por lo general la memoria en los dispositivos es muy escasa.

Comment: que libreria de render estas usando? vuetify?

Comment: Hola gracias por sus  comentarios , 
pregunté  en otros foros y me dijeron  que el problema podría ser los v-for anidados que tengo , dicen que es  un problema común y que el equipo de vueJS ya esta tratando de solucionarlo. eh agregado parte del codigo a mi pregunta.

Comment: donde dijeron eso, si fueran los v-for entonces todos estariamos en problemas... :/

Comment: A mi también me aprese muy raro ya que no tengo muchas posiciones  en los arreglos,  por otro lado hace un momento ingrese a la documentación oficial de vueJS desde mi celular y note que algunos ejemplos no funcionan desde mi dispositivo . por cierto uso vuetify.

Answer (score 2):

Tenia el mismo problema y la misma lógica de tu codigo , creaba dinamicamente los objetos, pero en realidad la razón fue la escasa memoria de los dispositivos móviles(como mencionan arriba) ,trate de solucionarlo haciendo [Code Splitting](https://medium.com/js-dojo/3-code-splitting-patterns-for-vuejs-and-webpack-b8fff1ea0ba4) , pero la solucion para mi fue crear un aplicación para móviles  ,utilice [XamarinForm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) , tenia la ventaja que tenia una web API, llegue hasta esta conclusión luego de investigar mucho, espero que mi experiencia te ayude

**Update**

Actualizando mi respuesta , con respecto a mi experiencia,estuve utilizando vuetify , y cambie a element ui , y todo comenzó a cambiar,aun en dispositivos moviles de bajos recursos la aplicación web corría super rápido.

Podría atreverme a decir que el problema era vuetify.